# Import statement causes bad indentation error

Tags: python

The relevant code is quite short:

```
class Gameserver:


def __init__(self):

    import modules.logic.game

        game.initGame()
        game.initGameInstance()
        game.start()
        game.myShowBase.run()
```

However, whatever I do,  I either get a bad indentation error (only in the first line that calls a function on game) or some of the functions are not called at all.
Any Ideas how to fix this?

Comment: The stuff after the import isn't a different block; don't indent it more.

Comment: Though the deeper issue here is probably that your `import` is in the wrong place.  There are very few cases where it makes sense to `import` in anything other than the module scope.

Comment: This code also has an indentation error in the class -- `__init__` should be indented further, though that might be a SO copy/paste error

Comment: There is a way to ACCEPT answers???

Comment: @user1862770 Of course. What did you think these outlined checkmarks are for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to type it as follows

```
class Gameserver:

    def __init__(self):
        import modules.logic.game
        game.initGame()
        game.initGameInstance()
        game.start()
        game.myShowBase.run()
```

This should not give you any error.

Comment: In fact it does.: The run -method from ShowBase is not found anymore.

Comment: In fact I have NO idea where this is coming from, the exact same code works fine if written into the main instead of the Gameserver class. Google gives seven links on my error message, one of which is in Chinese. The run() is underlined in red and I get: undefined variable from import: run.  I just do not know where to search anymore.#

Comment: @user1862770 i mean this should not give you `IndentationError` any more. The method not being found is a different error.

Comment: Well yes. But is the idea really that I ask another question for that? would not that be spamming if it is relates?

Answer (score 0):

Sam's code is correct, but overlooks a subsequent error (game not found).

```
from modules.logic import game

class Gameserver:
    def __init__(self):
        game.initGame()
        game.initGameInstance()
        game.start()
        game.myShowBase.run()
```

Comment: but it DOES work and game IS found...only showbase.run is doing funny stuff